# Delete empty and/or null values from a JSON

Tags: json, groovy

Given the following message:

```
[{
        "Name1": "Value1",
        "Name2": [{
                "Name2_1": [],
                "Name2_2": [{
                        "Name2_2_1": "Value2_2_1"}]
            }, {
                "Name2_3": [{
                        "Name2_3_1": 12300}
                ],
                "Name2_4": [{
                        "Name2_4_1": "Value2_4_1"}]
            }],
        "Name3": [{
                "Name3_1": "Value3_1"
            }]
    }, {
        "Name1": "Value1",
        "Name2": [{
                "Name2_1": 1234,
                "Name2_2": [{
                        "Name2_2_1": "Value2_2_1"
                    }],
                "Name2_3": []
            }],
        "Name3": []
    }]
```

I want to remove all the empty and/or null values using the Groovy programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
import groovy.json.* 

def data = '''\
[
  {
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": [
      {
        "Name2_1": [],
        "Name2_2": [
          {
            "Name2_2_1": "Value2_2_1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name2_3": [
          {
            "Name2_3_1": 12300
          }
        ],
        "Name2_4": [
          {
            "Name2_4_1": "Value2_4_1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Name3": [
      {
        "Name3_1": "Value3_1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": [
      {
        "Name2_1": 1234,
        "Name2_2": [
          {
            "Name2_2_1": "Value2_2_1"
          }
        ],
        "Name2_3": []
      }
    ],
    "Name3": []
  }
]'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)

json = recursivelyRemoveEmpties(json)

println(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json)))

def recursivelyRemoveEmpties(item) {
  switch(item) {
    case Map:
      return item.collectEntries { k, v ->
        [k, recursivelyRemoveEmpties(v)]
      }.findAll { k, v -> v }

    case List:
      return item.collect { 
        recursivelyRemoveEmpties(it) 
      }.findAll { v -> v }

    default: 
      return item
  }
}
```

defines a recursive method `recursivelyRemoveEmpties` which removes empty and null values from arbitrary depth in the data structure. When executed this prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
[
    {
        "Name1": "Value1",
        "Name2": [
            {
                "Name2_2": [
                    {
                        "Name2_2_1": "Value2_2_1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name2_3": [
                    {
                        "Name2_3_1": 12300
                    }
                ],
                "Name2_4": [
                    {
                        "Name2_4_1": "Value2_4_1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Name3": [
            {
                "Name3_1": "Value3_1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name1": "Value1",
        "Name2": [
            {
                "Name2_1": 1234,
                "Name2_2": [
                    {
                        "Name2_2_1": "Value2_2_1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Tested on:

```
─➤ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 3.0.6 JVM: 15.0.2 Vendor: Amazon.com Inc. OS: Linux
```